# Computing the entropy

Tags: code-golf, math

### Input

A matrix `M` represented as two space separated lines of integers. Each line will have the same number of integers and each integer will be either -1 or 1.  The number of integers per line will be at most 20.  `M` will therefore be `2` by `n` where `n` is the number of integers on each of the two lines.

Your code should be a complete program. <strike>and accept the input either on standard in or from a file (that is your choice).</strike> You can accept input from standard in, from a file or simply as a parameter. However, if you do the latter please give an explicit example of how your code should work and remember that it must be a complete program and how the matrix `M` will be represented in the input. In other words, you are likely to have to do some parsing.

### Output

The [binary Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of the distribution of `M*x` where the elements of `x` are uniformly and independently chosen from {-1,1}.   `x` is an `n`-dimensional column vector.

The entropy of a discrete probability distribution is

```
- sum p_i log_2(p_i)
```

In this case, `p_i` is the probability of the `i`th unique possible `M*x`.

### Example and helpful hints

As a worked example, let the matrix `M` be

```
-1 1
-1 -1
```

Now look at all `2^2` different possible vectors `x`. For each one we compute `M*x` and put all the results in an array (a 4-element array of 2-component vectors). Although for each of the 4 vectors the probability of it occurring is `1/2^2 = 1/4`, we are only interested in the number of times each *unique* resultant vector `M*x` occurs, and so we sum up the individual probabilities of the configurations leading to the same unique vectors. In other words, the possible unique `M*x` vectors describe the outcomes of the distribution we're investigating, and we have to determine the probability of each of these outcomes (which will, by construction, always be an integer multiple of `1/2^2`, or `1/2^n` in general) to compute the entropy.

In the general `n` case, depending on `M` the possible outcomes of `M*x` can range from "all different" (in this case we have `n` values of `i` in `p_i`, and each `p_i` is equal to `1/2^n`), to "all the same" (in this case there is a single possible outcome, and `p_1 = 1`).

Specifically, for the above `2x2` matrix `M` we can find by multiplying it with the four possible configurations (`[+-1; +-1]`), that each resulting vector is different. So in this case there are four outcomes, and consequently `p_1 = p_2 = p_3 = p_4 = 1/2^2 = 1/4`.  Recalling that `log_2(1/4) = -2` we have:

```
- sum p_i log_2(p_i) = -(4*(-2)/4) = 2
```

So the final output for this matrix is 2.

### Test cases

Input:

```
-1 -1 
-1 -1
```

Output:

```
1.5
```

Input:

```
-1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1
```

Output:

```
2.03063906223
```

Input:

```
-1  -1  -1  1
1  -1  -1  -1
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: 1. What are the dimensions of `x`? 2. In the interests of making the question self-contained, how is the binary Shannon entropy of `Mx` defined?

Comment: Can a function be written?

Comment: Also, check your test cases against the definition of entropy.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 It has to be a complete program. I am not sure what you mean by "check your test cases against the definition of entropy".  Can you explain more?

Comment: Why the downvotes??

Comment: @Peter's comment exactly explains the downvotes. I skimmed the article on entropy, and I can't immediately find out what to implement. You should specify exactly what the formula/algorithm is to compute Shannon entropy.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but: maybe explain how the output is obtained? Not just a link

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, anyway; it's unlikely that Wikipedia will suddenly go offline, but it would be ideal to not have to click through to another page to be able to understand the full specification of the challenge.

Comment: @dorothy, which definition are you using? All I can find is the definition for lists, not matrices.

Comment: I will add the entropy definition in a few hours. I was trying to find a nice way to paste in math.  In short it is just -sum p_i log_2(p_i)  where log_2(0) is taken to be 0 for convenience. p_i is the probability of outcome i.  If you can work out the probability of each possible outcome you can work out the entropy.  It doesn't matter what sort of object each outcome happens to be. In this case they are just 2 dimensional vectors.

Comment: Definition and worked example added.

Comment: By default, functions are a valid alternatives to programs. You are allowed to overrule that, but it will make some languages very sad because it takes lots of boilerplate to take file or stdin input. More broadly, I recommend against having such a restrictive input format on a mathematical challenge. Allowing the language's natural list type would make people happier to participate.

Comment: Also, since there haven't been any answers yet, I'd allow `M` to have integers that aren't just -1 and 1. I was just asking a question when I mentioned it to you in chat and I think the question would be better without this restriction, as well.

Comment: @dorothy note that it's not that "log_2(0) is 0 for convenience", but rather "lim_{p->0} p*log(p)==0". So "log_2(0)" is still -inf.

Comment: @dorothy I believe your problem is well-defined, but ill-described:) So I submitted an edit suggestion to make it clearer to others. Feel free to reject or improve it, it just seemed a simpler choice than trying to explain in comments what might be missing. The main point which most people missed was probably that only the number of unique resulting vectors are important, and the actual values are irrelevant. I think that if you sort this out, the question could be reopened.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I made a small tweak to your edit but other than that accepted it. Can it be reopened now?

Comment: dorothy, that is up to the high-rep users such as @xnor (I would vote to reopen, but then again I wouldn't have voted to close in the first place). Also: I've realized that even my solution does not comply with the rules: I need additional `[ ]` around the matrices to make it work. This is the same problem that xnor has mentioned. I could buff up my submission to make it work with the current rules, but I'd gladly avoid that if you would indeed consider lightening the input rules (much to the delight of a lot of users, I would think). If that helps, I could delete my answer for the time being.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I updated the rules.

Comment: @dorothy thanks, although I have to confess that the change is the exact opposite of what I had in mind:) Anyway, I've finally changed my submission to accommodate the input parsing criterion, at the cost of 28 extra bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>160</s> <s>159</s> 141 bytes

*includes +1 for `-p` since 141 byte update*

```
@y=(@z=/\S+/g)x 2**@z;@{$.}=map{evals/.1/"+".$&*pop@y/egr}glob"{-1,+1}"x@z}{$H{$_.$2[$i++]}++for@1;$\-=$_*log($_/=1<<@z)/log 2 for values%H;
```

The input is expected on `STDIN` as 2 lines consisting of space-separated `1` or `-1`.

Run as `perl -p 140.pl < inputfile`.

It won't win any prizes, but I thought I'd share my effort.
Explained:

```
    @y=                             # @y is (@z) x (1<<$n)
       (@z = /\S+/g)                # construct a matrix row from non-WS
       x 2**@z;                     # repeat @z 2^$n times
    @{$.} = map {                   # $.=$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER: set @1 or @2
      eval s/.1/"+".$&*pop@y/egr    # multiply matrix row with vector
    } glob "{-1,+1}" x @z           # produce all possible vectors

}{                                  # `-p` trick: end `while(<>)`, reset `$_`

$H{ $_ . $2[$i++] }++               # count unique M*x columns
    for @1;

$\ -= $_ * log($_/=1<<@z) / log 2   # sum entropy distribution
        for values %H;
```

**DATA**

- *update 159: save 1 by eliminating `()` by using `**` instead of `<<`.*
- *update 141: save 18 by using `$.` and `-p`.*

Comment: Thank you!  We don't have enough perl answers on ppcg imho

Comment: @dorothy It's because code-golfers _loathe_ Perl, for the most part.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam But, but.. perl is incomprehensible, succinct and borderline insane. How could it be *more* suitable for code-golf?

Comment: @dorothy ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ We avoid it like the plague. Dunno why, really.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 37 bytes

```
K^_B1lhJrR7.z_s*LldcRlKhMrSmms*VdkJK8
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%5E_B1lhJrR7.z_s%2aLldcRlKhMrSmms%2aVdkJK8&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-1+-1+%0A-1+-1%0A-1+-1+-1+-1%0A-1+-1+-1+-1%0A-1++-1++-1++1%0A1++-1++-1++-1&debug=0&input_size=2)

This is somewhat trickier when you have to manually implement matrix multiplication.

#### Explanation:

```
K^_B1lhJrR7.z_s*LldcRlKhMrSmms*VdkJK8
       JrR7.z                            Parse input into matrix, assign to J.
  _B1                                    [1, -1]
K^   lhJ                                 All +-1 vectors of length n, assign to K.
                           m       K     Map over K
                            m     J      Map over the rows of J
                             s*Vdk       Sum of vector product of vector and row.
                          S              Sort
                         r          8    Run length encode.
                       hM                Take just occurrence counts.
                   cRlK                  Divide by len(K) to get probabilities.
               *Lld                      Multiply each probabiliity by its log.
              s                          Sum.
             _                           Negate. Print implicitly.
```

Comment: Wow! :)  This looks like a lot of work. Now where are the cjam people..... ?

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <strike>48</strike> 68 bytes

Edit: Preprocess is added for accepting string as the parameter.

With the help of `Tuples` and `Entropy`, the implementation is both concise and readable.

```
Entropy[2,{-1,1}~Tuples~Length@#.#]&@Thread@ImportString[#,"Table"]&
```

where `Tuples[{-1,1},n]` gives all possible `n`-tuples from `{-1,1}`, and `Entropy[2,list]` gives the base-2 information entropy.

One of the cool things is that *Mathematica* will actually return an accurate expression:

```
%["-1 -1 \n -1 -1"]
(* 3/2 *)
```

Approximate result can be achieved with an extra `.` added (`Entropy[2., ...`).

Comment: Mathematica is ridiculous :)  However your answer doesn't quite fit the spec. The input is space separated so some parsing will be needed.  See the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

### MATLAB, <strike>196</strike> <strike>194</strike> <strike>187</strike> <strike>184</strike> <strike>126</strike> 154 bytes

(The extra 28 bytes from 126 to 154 are due to input parsing: now the code accepts the input as two lines of whitespace-separated numbers.)

```
f=@()str2num(input('','s'));M=[f();f()];n=size(M,2);x=(dec2bin(0:n^2-1,n)-48.5)*2*M';[~,~,c]=unique(x,'rows');p=accumarray(c,1)/2^n;disp(-sum(p.*log2(p)))
```

Ungolfed version:

```
f=@()str2num(input('','s'));        % shorthand for "read a line as vector"
M=[f();f()];                        % read matrix
n=size(M,2);                        % get lenght of vectors

x=(dec2bin(0:n^2-1,n)-48.5)*2*M';   % generate every configuration
                                    %    using binary encoding
[~,~,c]=unique(x,'rows');           % get unique rows of (Mx)^T
p=accumarray(c,1)/2^n;              % count multiplicities and normalize
disp(-sum(p.*log2(p)))              % use definition of entropy
```

I could do away with 6 bytes if an "`ans = ...`" type of output was allowed, I'm never sure about this.

I'm sorry to say that my original and *surely* witty solution was way too ungolfed compared to my current solution. This is also the first time I'm using `accumarray`. A six-input-parameter application still has to wait, though:)

Outputs (following `format long`):

```
[-1 1
-1 -1]
     2

[-1 -1
-1 -1]
   1.500000000000000

[-1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1]
   2.030639062229566

[-1  -1  -1  1
1  -1  -1  -1]
     3
```

Outputs with the default `format short g`:

```
[-1 1
-1 -1]
     2

[-1 -1
-1 -1]
          1.5

[-1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1]
       2.0306

[-1  -1  -1  1
1  -1  -1  -1]
     3
```